# ASP.NET MVC 2 validation LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model

Currently I have a DataModel object which contains my linq to sql classes(a dmbl file). Currently I use a partial class to validate the incoming input. For example

```
public partial class User : IEntity
{

    public NameValueCollection CheckModel()
    {
        return GetRuleViolations();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method validates incoming data, by given rules in the if statement.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>NameValueCollection</returns>
    private NameValueCollection GetRuleViolations()
    {
        NameValueCollection errors = new NameValueCollection();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
            errors.Add("Username", "A username is required");
        // and so on
        return errors;
    }

}
```

Now what I want to try to do is add validation attributes to the fields. For example I want to try to add the required attribute to the field Username instead/in addtion of using the validation I currently have. My question is how can I achieve this because the dmbl file is auto generated. Or maybe it is not possible and should I use a different approach?

Comment: You will have to generate your own L2S classes. Look for T4 templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about Metadata classes. This is example [blog entry](http://blogs.renacimiento.com/eblanco/archive/2010/01/14/using-dataannotations-metadata-with-linq2sql-entities.aspx) about it.

Adding `Required` atrribute to `User` class will be something like:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public partial class User
{
}

public class UserMetadata
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might also find the following links interesting: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28VS.100%29.aspx

DataAnnotations is the keyword in this situations. ASP.Net MVC 2 even supports client side validation for this kind of validations.