# Linq2Sql and Client Validation seems not to be working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I have a class generated by the Linq2Sql. I try to add the client validation to its properties, so I do the following:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ResourceMetadata))]
public partial class Resource
{
  // Resource is a class in the LINQ to SQL generated data context.
}

public class ResourceMetadata
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "error !")]
  public string NewsTitle { get; set; } // the NewsTitle property is also in generated Resource class
}
```

then, in my View,

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<%Html.EnableClientValidation(true); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsTitle) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsTitle) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsTitle) %>
    </div>

     <input type="submit" value="Create" />
<% } %>
```

the Web.config file

> appSettings
>
> ```
> add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"
> add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"
> add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"
> ```
>
> appSettings

but still, the validation is not working, nothing shows, the model is passed to the server. Why ?

### [SOLVED]

### The namespaces of the generated class and my class were different. I had to change them to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't enabled in View page.

Use this

```
Html.ValidationSummary(true) // you have set it false
```

Comment: yes, not working even if I set Html.ValidationSummary(false). I've followed by this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2499352/106616

Comment: Are the Linq2Sql generated classes and MetaData classes in the same assembly?

Comment: I fixed it - my own class was in different namespace. When they were the same - it worked. I didn't know that it is important cuz I'm new in the partial classes. Thanks guys !

Comment: The moment @epignosisx asked this question and i had the feeling he is hit the nail on the head. Thanks to him and good luck to you :-)